# Since June 2023 Chrome 114 Update, I Can No Longer Attach to Existing Instance of Chrome with Selenium Basic for VBA

Tags: vba, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have Selenium Basic for VBA installed on my work Windows 10 computer which I use to automate Chrome.

Recently, my office updated Chrome to version 114.0.5735.135 (Official Build) (64-bit) (cohort: Stable).

Since the update, I can no longer attach to an existing instance of Chrome with VBA.

I updated ChromeDriver.exe to 114.0.5735.90 based on the instructions here: https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads/version-selection

Prior to the update, I could attach to an existing instance of chrome in VBA by starting Chrome with the following command: `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --remote-debugging-port=9222 --enable-logging --v=1` and running, for example, the following VBA procedure:

```
Sub botTest()
Dim bot As ChromeDriver
Set bot = New ChromeDriver
bot.SetCapability "debuggerAddress", "localhost:9222"
bot.get ("https://www.example.com") '***Error Thrown Here***
End Sub
```

Since the update I get following error on the `bot.get(https://www.example.com)` line:

```
UnknownError
unknown error: cannot connect to chrome at localhost:9222
from chrome not reachable
  (Driver info: chromedriver=114.0.5735.90 (386bc09e8f4f2e025eddae123f36f6263096ae49-refs/branch-heads/5735@{#1052}),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64)
```

If I delete the `bot.SetCapability "debuggerAddress", "localhost:9222"` line, the program runs, creating a new instance of Chrome.

Before the update, I was able to attach to an existing instance of Chrome.

Thanks.

I don't see how this could be a duplicate since question specifically relates to the July 2023 update of Chrome. Prior to the update, I could attach to an existing instance of Chrome.